# How to add dynamically rows in datatable using textbox field ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I need to add dynamically with 3 text box field
[image]

It works but the problem is I can't save the previews records 'cause the data table rewrite in the event the object.

```
 private void AgregarFila()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Fecha", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("Documento", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("Folio", typeof(Int32));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) // It is only for testing
    {
        dtRow = dt.NewRow();
        dtRow["Fecha"] = Session["HCfecha"];
        dtRow["Documento"] = Session["HCDocumento"];
        dtRow["Folio"] = Session["HCFolio"];
        dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
    }
    gvHistoriaLaboral.DataSource = dt;
    gvHistoriaLaboral.DataBind();
}
```

View.aspx

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="gvHistoriaLaboral" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-striped" runat="server"></asp:DataGrid>
```

help!

Comment: Please clarify: Are you saying the data will not save, and when you BIND to the grid nothing shows up? If so run dt.AccepChanges() after your FOR LOOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your DataTable in the Session so it's accesible later on, like this:

```
private void AgregarFila()
{
    if (Session["miTabla"] == null) //New table, create table and save it with the new record in Session variable
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Fecha", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Documento", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Folio", typeof(Int32));
        dtRow = dt.NewRow();
        dtRow["Fecha"] = Session["HCfecha"];
        dtRow["Documento"] = Session["HCDocumento"];
        dtRow["Folio"] = Session["HCFolio"];
        dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        Session["miTabla"] = dt;
    }
   else
    {
        dt = (DataTable) Session["miTabla"]; //Read Session variable
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
           dtRow = dt.NewRow();
           dtRow["Fecha"] = Session["HCfecha"];
           dtRow["Documento"] = Session["HCDocumento"];
           dtRow["Folio"] = Session["HCFolio"];
           dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        }
        Session["miTabla"] = dt;   //Write Session variable after record added     
   }
    gvHistoriaLaboral.DataSource = dt;
    gvHistoriaLaboral.DataBind();
}
```

The Session variable value stays for the current user session so whenever a new record is inserted you just read that variable, parse it to a DataTable, add the new record and then store the DataTable back in the Session.

For more information or other ways of doing it: [ASP .NET State Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

Regards!